# put button in one line with same space between all button

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

i want to put five button in bottom but all button should be with same space means

below is image

[image]

Here you can see that second and third image is not in center below is my code i know that i have put padding but still my problem is not solving, i have tried using linearlayout also in that i have done by using weight=1 and width =0 but button is stretching

```
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wall"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/check_right" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butfav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/fvrt1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/check_left" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butSetWallpaper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/butLeft"
    android:background="@drawable/chek_wallpaper" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butSetRingTone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/butRight"
    android:background="@drawable/check_ringtone" />
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: you shouldn't apply the layout_weight to the buttons itself, but to the spacing views that you put in between the buttons. layout_weight will cause the spacing views to occupy all the space that's not already "used" by your buttons. Use the same layout_weight for each spacing view to get equal spacing, don't apply a weightSum to the parent-LinearLayout. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried below code it's worked for me try this, just replace with your RelativeLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/butLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/check_left" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/butOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/check_right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/butSetWallpaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/chek_wallpaper" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/butTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/check_right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/butfav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fvrt1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/butThree"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/check_right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/butSetRingTone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/check_ringtone" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/butFour"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/check_right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/butRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/check_right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

out put will be generated as you wish

Comment: Ya by this way it's working fine thank you so much Siddhpura Amit

Answer (score 2):

I always use LinearLayout to achieve this and instead Buttons I'm using ImageView.

Comment: i have done it by weight = 1, and width = 0 but all button are stretching.. can you provide me code?

Comment: is it possible by this? still imageview will not be stretch?

Comment: If you use android:src instead android:background, should be alright. Plus in ImageView you can setup scaleType.

Comment: The image won't stretch with scaleType-center, however the clickable area is still going to be stretched.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the buttons in a LinearLayout and put spacings between each button (i also added one at the beginning and one after the last one, remove them if you don't want it).

assign a layout_weight for each spacing, don't set a weightSum on the LinearLayout.

Enjoy.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <!-- this is for the spacing -->
            <View
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/butRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/check_right" />

            <!-- this is for the spacing -->
            <View
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/butfav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/fvrt1" />

            <!-- this is for the spacing -->
            <View
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/butLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/check_left" />

            <!-- this is for the spacing -->
            <View
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/butSetWallpaper"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/chek_wallpaper" />

            <!-- this is for the spacing -->
            <View
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/butSetRingTone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/check_ringtone" />

            <!-- this is for the spacing -->
            <View
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Its a bit dirty solution but It'll work :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/aaaa"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bbbb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butfav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cccc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ddd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butSetWallpaper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gggg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/butSetRingTone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:minWidth="48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why all of you doing trick with code. In android coding there is option available to give space between item.

```
  <Space
        android:id="@+id/space1"

        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        />
```

Just use this  whenever you want. simple. hope this will help you.